# Виджет ВК обрезает картинки при просмотре с мобильного

Tags: вконтакте, виджет, комментарии

Проблема с виджетом комментариев от *ВК*: при просмотре сайта с телефона в виджете комментариев картинки обрезаются и не заливаются по ширине.

Как это исправить?

**Так должно быть**:

[image: Как должно быть]

**Вот так сейчас**:

[image: Вот так сейчас((((]

Answer (score 1):

Поставить картинкам:

```
max-width: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

Это наверное из-за того что картинке и его родителю задаются статичные размеры. Надо CSS'ом менять.

Comment: Дайте ссылку на сайт, помогу.

Comment: вот сайт - zombitime.com

Answer (score 0):

Вот, добавь в CSS:

```
.page_post_sized_thumbs.clear_fix {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}

.page_post_thumb_wrap .page_post_thumb_last_column .page_post_thumb_last_row { 
    width: auto!important; 
    height: auto!important; 
}

.page_post_thumb_sized_photo { 
    width: 100%!important; 
    height: auto!important; 
    position: relative;
}

.page_post_thumb_sized_photo {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}

.page_post_thumb_wrap.page_post_thumb_last_column.page_post_thumb_last_row {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}

.page_post_sized_thumbs.clear_fix {
    width: 100%!important;
    height: auto!important;
}
```

Comment: вставил в style.css но не помогло, картинки в комментариях от контакта обрезанные так и остались(